# To add google group as claims into a token

Tags: google-oauth, openid, jwt, google-identity

We would like to use google as identity provider for our own identity server. My problem is I would like to generate a jwt access token on our identity server side which contains google groups (Google for education group actually). For to do that I have to get from google the groups during my authorization request. I follow the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect)

Could you recommend best way how to get user groups? Is it possible in general?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be for Google to provide group claims, like [Azure does](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/). For the time being you'll need to use [the List method in the Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list).

Comment: FYI this seems to be the ticket for adding that in Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133774835